# How to write a Makefile rule to filter out C files in a Go project?

Tags: c, go, makefile

I have a Go project with the structure:

```
test
 |
 never
 |
 |-gonna
    |
    |---give.c
    |---give.go
    |---give.h
    |---give_you_up.go
```

My build in my Makefile looks like this:

```
build: ## Build service
ifeq ($(CPU_TYPE),arm64)
    $Q cd $(BASE) && \
    $(GO) build $(filter-out ./never/gonna/give.go ./never/gonna/give_you_up.go, $(wildcard *.go) $(wildcard ./subpackage/*.go)) ; \
    $(info $(M) $(BASE))
```

My base is `/Users/navid/Desktop/test`

Is this the right way to filter out the go files from the project, and how do I filter out the c file as well?

Comment: Why do you need to filter out the `.c` file? It won't appear in the output of either of those `wildcard` statements.